# How to change permissions in facebook session?

Tags: android, facebook, session, facebook-android-sdk

I'm developening my android application using facebook sdk 3.5. I setted several permissions in my developening time . now i want to reduce number of permission because my object session contains old permissions setted. how can i do it?

```
{Session state:OPENED, token:{AccessToken token:ACCESS_TOKEN_REMOVED permissions:[read_stream, publish_checkins, status_update, photo_upload, video_upload, create_note, share_item, publish_stream, publish_actions, user_likes, user_photos, user_videos, user_photo_video_tags, user_friends, friends_likes, friends_photos, friends_videos, friends_photo_video_tags, basic_info]}, appId=xxxx}
```

I need only few permission above...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved deleting application from facebook, so I reseted the permission.
https://www.facebook.com/settings?tab=applications

Answer (score 0):

You can try this,

```
    final OpenRequest openRequest = new Session.OpenRequest((Activity) context);

    List<String> permissions = new ArrayList<String>();
    permissions.add("email");
    openRequest.setPermissions(permissions);
```

and then after checking access token loading you can write this

```
session.openForRead(openRequest.setCallback(statusCallback));
```

The above mention process works for me as i only needed users email.

Hope this will help..